# Too much padding/spacing but not in code

Tags: css, html, wordpress, padding

You were all so helpful last time,  I'm hoping you can help me with something that has been bugging me for the last 2 days...

I installed a plugin on Wordpress called Snazzy Archives to show my archives in an interesting way. I like it, it's great BUT for some reason, there's a massive space between my H1 tag and my archives.. and the other thing that's annoying me is that I can't seem to get any spacing between the header image and the H1 tag, despite it being there on every other page...

Anyone able to help with this? The problematic page is http://www.electrickiwi.co.uk/blog/archives

Thanks!

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following in your markup:

```
<p>
<code> </code>
</p>
```

Right below the **Post Archives** `h1`. You should also review the margin and padding on the bottom of the `h1`; currently, it's adding about `26px` total space between.

And then, to fix the spacing of the `h1` to the menu above it, add `clear: both;` to the `div id="container4"`.

Also, your `div class="snazzy"` has a child `code` block that doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for responding. I've taken this out using Firebug but it doesn't fully remove the spacing problem I've got. I've also tried removing this but it's not in the template code and can't find it in the plugin code either... this one really has me totally confused!

Comment: That seems to be there with the plugin, I didn't write that code there. The code block doesn't even appear when I look in the template or the plugin code. This is seriously driving me crazy..

Comment: I don't think they're actually causing any mischief now that I look at it more closely; they appear just to be there (for no reason that I can see). See my edit.

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks again - you've fixed my spacing between the H1 and the menu. I'm still not able to get rid of this spacing between the H1 and the archives box. It's not a major issue now though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a stray `<p><code></code></p>` in there for some reason (maybe the Snazzy developer uses that for debugging and forgot to take it out?); you'll need to search to find the closing elements. But you need to find it and take it out.

Comment: Also, please consider upvoting this answer and selecting it as the answer (by hitting the checkmark next to the answer) if you think this answered your question. Also note, you can only mark one answer as the right answer. `:)`

Comment: I'm not seeing the `<p><code>` written explicitly in the Snazzy code itself (which I downloaded). In `snazzy-template.php`, `$SnazzyArchives->display("");` is called, with `get_header()` and `get_footer()` wrapping it. My guess is this is where the `<p><code>` is coming from, or at least to investigate it.

Comment: And if you *really* can't figure it out, you could possibly use jQuery to find and remove it: http://jsfiddle.net/B77N8/.

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of removing

```
<p>
<code> </code>
</p>
```

and setting a `margin:0; padding:0` to your `h1.archives`

Comment: <p>
<code> </code>
</p>

doesn't appear in the template.. it does when I view source with Firebug but there is nothing in the template or the plugin code.. I have no idea where that is coming from and I'm so sure that is what's causing the problem!